# How to get Modules Name in HMVC Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I have a couple of controllers in two modules with same name and both works fine. also i have a function for checking access permission, it uses `$this->router->fetch_class()`.
 problem is `$this->router->fetch_class()` returns controller name and it's the same. but i need Modules name too.

Structure of the Modules

```
/modules
    /product
        /controllers
            /product.php
            /options.php [1]
        /models
        /views
    /inventory
        /controllers
            /inventory.php
            /options.php [2]
        /models
        /views
```

and urls are:

```
[1]: ../product/options/function_name
[2]: ../inventory/options/function_name
```

so is there any way to check access permission without changing controllers name?

Comment: Please use routes file there you change url as you desired.

Comment: i don't completely understand your comment but i think routes not the problem because controller works.

Comment: take a look @ https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html - this should provide you enough information.
Btw: Since CI doesn't support Namespaces properly its not adivsable to use same classnames twice in a project because you can run easily in a conflict - especially if you use HMVC - because you can call other modules/controllers with `Modules::run()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [@sintakonte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3436643/sintakonte) said, you can use the [uri library](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html).

Using `segment` you can get each part of the url.

Module names are always the first part after your domain.

```php
$module_name = $this->uri->segment(1);
```